# Mongodb Java MapReduce getOutputCollection

Tags: java, collections, mapreduce, inline

I don't know anything about the OutputTypes. I'm trying something like this:

```
output=collection.mapReduce(map,reduce,null,
  MapReduceCommand.OutputType.INLINE,null);
collection=output.getOutputCollection();
```

But the collection is null, because of the INLINE output type. I need the reduced collection because I need to reduce it further. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this finally

```
output=collection.mapReduce(map,reduce,"mymap",MapReduceCommand.OutputType. REDUCE,null); 
collection=output.getOutputCollection();
```

note that you cannot store in same target "mymap" again and again. You have to use different name when you are looping like `"mymap".concat(Integer.toString(i))`